# Set LogStreamName for AWS Lambda call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We deploy node.js functions onto AWS Lambda. When calling them, they auto-generate an AWS CloudWatch log. The log group is set to the name of the Lambda function, that´s helpful. But the log stream is named like this: `2018/02/14/[$LATEST]794dbaf40a7846c4984ad80ebf110544`.

[image: AWS CloudWatch Log Streams]

That is not helpful when searching for errors since I need to check multiple log streams, because I do not know which one is the correct one.

Is there any way to define the log stream name, so that it is more readable for a human being?

The node.js code looks similar to this:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log('Called "' + context.functionName + '" with AWS-Request-Id "' + context.awsRequestId + '"');
    // do sth. here
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Check out the context of your function. It has property `context.logStreamName`. You could change it to any unique name.</s>

Keep in mind, if you want to append your logs to existed stream, you have to persist its token. It was the reason why I created new log stream for each lambda call. Also, I am using guid for creating stream name (like: `reason why log created + guid()`, timestamp is ok as well).

Check more details in the next article - [The Context Object (Node.js)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html)

**EDIT**: Don't pay attention to my previous answer. It was completely wrong.

I checked my code how I implemented the same functionality. It isn't possible to change group or stream name from the context. But you could use [CloudWatchLogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html) in your code for putting logs in specific group and stream.

My code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({ apiVersion: '2014-03-28' });

    // create new stream name for each request
    // because I don't persist sequenceToken
    var logStreamName = "myStreamName" + Math.random()

    var params = {
        logGroupName: 'myLogGroup',
        logStreamName: logStreamName
    };
    cloudwatchlogs.createLogStream(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            var params = {
                logEvents: [{
                        message: 'log message',
                        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                    },
                    {
                        message: 'one more log message',
                        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                    }
                ],
                logGroupName: 'myLogGroup',
                logStreamName: logStreamName
            };

            cloudwatchlogs.putLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else console.log(data); // successful response
            });
        }
    });
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

Disadvantages of this approach are:

- Your lambda creates two logGroups and two logStreams in accordance. One of your lambda, another custom. `console.log('')` writes to lambda log, `putLogEvents` writes to your custom log (i.e: myStreamName0.10141409975385463). Be aware of this.
- You have to create manually 'myLogGroup' (how I did) or implement code that will create a logGroup if it doesn't exist.

The result of this testing code looks like:
[image]

My productions stream names have more sense rather name + random. And they are using guid or timestamp as a suffix. I don't think that it is safe to use random.

Comment: I don´t think I can change this context property. I tried it but it doesn´t make any difference...

Comment: @Tobias I have updated my answer. Sorry for the wrong first attempt.

Comment: Thanks @RredCat, I´ll try that later!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the Log Stream name. Each running container for your Lambda function logs into a different Log Stream.

If you want to easily see the logs together as one, you can stream them to [Amazon ElasticSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html) so you can use Kibana to browse through your logs or you can use CLI tools like [`awscli`](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs) to aggregate and browse them in your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep track of the executions anyway like in my case there is also a less redundant approach:

Just create a dynamodb table "Executions" and make sure to push a new entry on every lambda execution with both the `logStreamName` (which can be accessed from context) and your custom name or other custom information that you need to look up this logStream.

Upsides:

- no wrapper/custom logging logic necessary.
- no duplicate entries in cloudwatch

Downsides:

- you might need to do an additional call to dynamodb to find out the logStreamName as the logStreamName itself has no identifying value
- no considerations about IAM and access so far. you have to take that in mind in your setup