# Monitoring on aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My python3 lambda functions process records from dynamodb. I am printing every step of my lambda execution in cloudwatch. Now I am at a stage of deploying and monitoring my lambdas in production. Is there a way I can know which records are executed by lambda as a whole in consolidated way?

I am also using X-ray to understand how much time and errors that my lambdas are taking. Besides, measuring the duration, invocation, errors. I want a way to know how many records are executed? thanks.

Comment: Are you using DynamoDB streams with a trigger out to your python3 lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CloudWatchLogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) for logging in the custom log group and log stream.

You will be able to change in the configuration names group/stream during the deployment to different stages.

Check out how to do it with boto3 - [Client.put_log_events](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events)

You could check my sample for NodeJS - [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48807502/182344). The code is much simpler and graceful for python.

**PS:** Drop me a comment if you have any issue with converting.

Answer (score 0):

While printing every line to log might help you to debug and troubleshoot your code, this is a very manual and not scaleable option. In addition, you would lose your mind going through endless logs.

In the serverless world (and specifically in AWS, where you have Lambda, DynamoDB, SQS, SNS, API Gateway, and lots of other resources), you should use the right tools that will give you visibility into your architecture, allow you to troubleshoot issues quickly, and will identify serverless specific issues (timeouts, out of memory, ..).

One thing you can try out is to [stream out all your logs](https://github.com/gilt/cloudwatch-elk) from CloudWatch to an external service such as ELK. It will allow you to easily explore them.

Otherwise, I'm recommending to use a dedicated solution for serverless - there are several out there (our own [Epsagon](https://epsagon.com), IOpipe, Dashbird).

Comment: This is marginally spammy … you’re essentially making a sales pitch, offering no solution except to use your product.

Comment: Please have a look at [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and adapt your post to include detailed instructions, while continuing to clearly disclose your affiliation. Otherwise your post might get removed.

Comment: Guy, I don't agree with you. CloudWatch is not the right solution for production debugging. It's won't work for him to look for billions of log rows.
He prefers to use managed services such as Lambda and DynamoDB, so why should he compromise the monitoring and do it by himself???
Anyways, I've added at least a tutorial on how to stream out logs from CW to ELK. much better than using CW console, but IMO, still requires manual work.